# HowTo? Debug PHPMailer function as it is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I have a couple of websites and my host has PHPMailer enabled.

On a wordpress site I also installed a plugin which returned this result:

```
bool(true)
The full debugging output is shown below:
object(PHPMailer)#81 (69) {
  ["Version"]=>
  string(5) "5.2.7"
  ["Priority"]=>
  int(3)
  ["CharSet"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["ContentType"]=>
  string(10) "text/plain"
  ["Encoding"]=>
  string(4) "8bit"
  ["ErrorInfo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["From"]=>
  string(23) "test@gmail.com"
  ["FromName"]=>
  string(10) "StackOverflow"
  ["Sender"]=>
  string(23) "test@gmail.com"
  ["ReturnPath"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(48) "WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to test@gmail.com"
  ["Body"]=>
  string(68) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin."
  ["AltBody"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Ical"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MIMEBody":protected]=>
  string(69) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin.
"
  ["MIMEHeader":protected]=>
  string(356) "Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 03:57:46 +0000
Return-Path: 
From: Test Test 
Message-ID: <8c0bcf9002be1e7eba1b4e3a2282c3d5@domain.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
"
  ["mailHeader":protected]=>
  string(84) "To: test@gmail.com
Subject: WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to test@gmail.com
"
  ["WordWrap"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Mailer"]=>
  string(4) "mail"
  ["Sendmail"]=>
  string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
  ["UseSendmailOptions"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PluginDir"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ConfirmReadingTo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Hostname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageID"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageDate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["Port"]=>
  int(25)
  ["Helo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SMTPSecure"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SMTPAuth"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["Username"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["AuthType"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Realm"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Workstation"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Timeout"]=>
  int(10)
  ["SMTPDebug"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["Debugoutput"]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  ["SMTPKeepAlive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleTo"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleToArray"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["do_verp"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["AllowEmpty"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["LE"]=>
  string(1) "
"
  ["DKIM_selector"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_identity"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_passphrase"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_domain"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_private"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["action_function"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["XMailer"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["smtp":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["to":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(21) "test@gmail.com"
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["cc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["bcc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ReplyTo":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["all_recipients":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["test@gmail.com"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["attachment":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["CustomHeader":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["lastMessageID":protected]=>
  string(51) "<8c0bcf9002be1e7eba1b4e3a2282c3d5@domain.com>"
  ["message_type":protected]=>
  string(5) "plain"
  ["boundary":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(35) "b1_8c0bcf9002be1e7eba1b4e3a2282c3d5"
    [2]=>
    string(35) "b2_8c0bcf9002be1e7eba1b4e3a2282c3d5"
    [3]=>
    string(35) "b3_8c0bcf9002be1e7eba1b4e3a2282c3d5"
  }
  ["language":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["sign_cert_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_pass":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["exceptions":protected]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

How can I debug and test this to figure out a solution as none of my on line forms are sending.

Any workarounds would be appreciated too though I've already considered using SMTP and prefer not to...  I have tried the classic mail() function and that did not work either.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the code which causes the error in addition to the debug log?

Comment: Hi Marc. That's what I am asking, how to debug and find an error. I don't really know, it's a little out of my depth but I'm willing to learn.

Comment: Locate your wp function, which handles processing your form data. Add some debugging to this function as `var_dump()`. Also try firebug to see what is send to the server and what is the response.

Comment: Have had a search, can't find the wp function... Will it be a php file in the wp directories? I've googled var_dump and will do this when located file. Firebug I didn't see anything moving when sending through the form though am not experienced using it...

Comment: First you really need to find the code handling form processing and mail sending (it's not necessary one function) to start debugging. If we are talking about WP, it will be most probably  in a WP plugin. That's where you should start looking. It is also strange that firebug doesn't catch any request after form submission, there is "no other way" to send data to server other then HTTP request (classic form submission or XHR request mostly in WP). Last tip is to look at your front end HTML code and get some elements with ID attributes, then perform fulltext search for IDs on your PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Object dump, your SMTP property is NULL which in most cases will mean that it is not configured properly. If you could provide the code sample that is trying to use the PHPMailer or at least some details on the current configuration.